# Add percentage to the column in tab delimted text

Tags: awk

How to add this percentage column if you have multiple columns ahead

Like below

```
Ref Alt Ref_count   Alt_Count   Per (%) Func    Ge
TGA T   2   2       ab  PRKCZ
TGA c   6   6       ab  PRKCZ
TGA C   8   7       ab  PRKCZ
TGA T   9   3       ab  PRKCZ
TGA C   9   3       ab  PRKCZ
TGA T   9   3       ab  PRKCZ
TGA C   9   5       ab  PRKCZ
TGA T   9   3       ab  PRKCZ
TGA C   5   2       ab  PRKCZ
TGA T   4   3       ab  PRKCZ
```

And calculate percentage of column 4 by column 3. Keeping other columns and headers intact

Output should look like this

```
Ref Alt Ref_count   Alt_Count   Per (%) Func    Ge
TGA T   2   2   100.00% ab  PRKCZ
TGA c   6   6   100.00% ab  PRKCZ
TGA C   8   7   87.50%  ab  PRKCZ
TGA T   9   3   33.33%  ab  PRKCZ
TGA C   9   3   33.33%  ab  PRKCZ
TGA T   9   3   33.33%  ab  PRKCZ
TGA C   9   5   55.56%  ab  PRKCZ
TGA T   9   3   33.33%  ab  PRKCZ
TGA C   5   2   40.00%  ab  PRKCZ
TGA T   4   3   75.00%  ab  PRKCZ
```

I used command from link
[How to Add Column with Percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303367/how-to-add-column-with-percentage/50265636#50265636)

awk 'NR==FNR{a = a + $2;next} {c = ($2/a)*100;print $1,$2,c }' file file

But its returning only three columns and not the remaining data.
Output is below

```
Ref_count   Alt_Count   0
2   2   0.00968429
6   6   0.0290529
8   7   0.033895
9   3   0.0145264
9   3   0.0145264
9   3   0.0145264
9   5   0.0242107
9   3   0.0145264
5   2   0.00968429
4   3   0.0145264
```

Comment: `print $1,$2,c` cannot produce the output you say it does from the input file you posted since `$1` in the input is `TGA` for every non-header line and I find it extremely hard to believe that you can't figure out why `print $1,$2,c` outputs 3 values and amend it to print the rest. Just take a few seconds to think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `column` to align the columns:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}NR>1{$5=sprintf("%.2f%",$4/$3*100 )}1' file | column -t -s $'\t'
Ref  Alt  Ref_count  Alt_Count  Per (%)  Func Ge
TGA  T    2          2          100.00%  ab   PRKCZ
TGA  c    6          6          100.00%  ab   PRKCZ
TGA  C    8          7          87.50%   ab   PRKCZ
TGA  T    9          3          33.33%   ab   PRKCZ
TGA  C    9          3          33.33%   ab   PRKCZ
TGA  T    9          3          33.33%   ab   PRKCZ
TGA  C    9          5          55.56%   ab   PRKCZ
TGA  T    9          3          33.33%   ab   PRKCZ
TGA  C    5          2          40.00%   ab   PRKCZ
TGA  T    4          3          75.00%   ab   PRKCZ
```

Explained:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }                # have and keep tab as field delimiter
NR>1 {                               # dont process header line
    $5=sprintf("%.2f%%",$4/$3*100 )  # use sprintf to control decimals
}1' file
```

Comment: Quicker than me and better answer+1!

Comment: That would replace $5 instead of inserting a new field between $4 and $5 (it wouldn't produce the output you say it does). Also, the sprintf format string should be `"%.2f%%"` for portability - right now you're relying on undefined behavior by assuming a `%` at the end of the formatting string will be printed as-is but some awks (e.g OSX awk) will produce a syntax error instead.

Comment: @EdMorton Not sure what you mean with the false output; the fifth field is empty and surrounded by tabs on both sides and I set `FS="\t"`? Also, thanks for the tip on `%%`. I wish I had more awks to test these scripts with but only gawk, mawk and nawk (original-awk) are available.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know there was an empty field in the input, idk how you figured that out but nice work and sorry for the misfire! nawk is not original awk btw - oawk (/bin/awk on Solaris) is original awk, aka old, broken awk. nawk is just another very old awk that's newer than and fixes a lot of the problems with oawk.

Comment: I edited the OP and cut the data from there. Ah, ok, in my Debian there is "original-awk` which seems to be the same as nawk (awk version 20121220).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following `awk` command as well, even if [James Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4162356/james-brown) answer is nicer

```
awk 'NR==1{print}NR>1{per=($4/$3*100); printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%2f%%\t%s\t%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,per,$5,$6}' inputF | column -t
Ref  Alt  Ref_count  Alt_Count  Per          (%)  Func   Ge
TGA  T    2          2          100.000000%  ab   PRKCZ
TGA  c    6          6          100.000000%  ab   PRKCZ
TGA  C    8          7          87.500000%   ab   PRKCZ
TGA  T    9          3          33.333333%   ab   PRKCZ
TGA  C    9          3          33.333333%   ab   PRKCZ
TGA  T    9          3          33.333333%   ab   PRKCZ
TGA  C    9          5          55.555556%   ab   PRKCZ
TGA  T    9          3          33.333333%   ab   PRKCZ
TGA  C    5          2          40.000000%   ab   PRKCZ
TGA  T    4          3          75.000000%   ab   PRKCZ
```

**Explanations:**

- `NR==1{print}` prints the 1st line
- `{per=($4/$3*100); printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%2f%%\t%s\t%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,per,$5,$6}` is used to compute the ratio of the 4th/3rd column and then print the result using `printf` function in order to have the number of decimals required everything separated by tabs. You can use the `column` command to have a nice display.

Comment: Thank you very much Allan for your reply.